# How can I read the first line of a file into a character array?

Tags: c++

I am doing a textbook exercise that requires scoring student tests.

The input file looks like:

```
TTFTFTTTFTFTFFTTFTTF
ABC54102 T FTFTFTTTFTTFTTF TF
DEF56278 TTFTFTTTFTFTFFTTFTTF
ABC42366 TTFTFTTTFTFTFFTTF
ABC42586 TTTTFTTT TFTFFFTF
```

The first line is the answer key for a test, and the following lines are student IDs and their responses, with blanks as an unanswered question.

The very first thing I need to do is read the first line so that I have something to compare the responses to. My first thought is to use a character array, but I can't seem to get it right. The first method I tried is:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

const int NUM_QUESTIONS = 20;

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Vars
    char answers[NUM_QUESTIONS];
    ifstream infile;

    // Open File
    infile.open("Ch8_Ex6Data.txt");

    infile.getline(answers, NUM_QUESTIONS);
    cout << answers << endl;
    infile.getline(answers, NUM_QUESTIONS);
    cout << answers << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Which outputs

```
TTFTFTTTFTFTFFTTFTT
```

This is the all of the answers, but I noticed I couldn't do this twice to get to the next line. The second getline() sees an empty string.

The second method I tried was:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

const int NUM_QUESTIONS = 20;

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Vars
    char answers[NUM_QUESTIONS];
    ifstream infile;

    // Open File
    infile.open("Ch8_Ex6Data.txt");

    // Read first line into character array
    infile.getline(answers, '\n');
    cout << answers;

    return 0;
}
```

Which outputs:

```
TTFTFTTTF
```

Which clearly isn't the whole line.

What should I do from here?

Comment: `getline` reads `NUM_QUESTIONS` chars and keeps `\n`, an empty line for next `getline`, call it with a single std::string argument.

Comment: `infile.getline(answers, '\n');` is invalid, that overload is for `std::string`, but you actually call it with the array `infile.getline(answers, 10);`, thus you get 10 chars.

Comment: In C++ you should steer towards using `std::string` if only to avoid the endless misery that is C strings.

Comment: Where you should go from here is the next chapter in your textbook that will, hopefully, explain what `std::string` is and how it works. It'll make this program much, much easier.

Comment: I have to ask, but how old is your textbook? Because std::string and std::vector have been around since C++98 and any decent book should cover them by now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `std::ifstream` and `std::getline()` for this.

First, create a new input file stream and initialize with the file:

```
std::ifstream file("filename");
```

Then, get the line: (The `getline()` function will read all until a newline character)

```
std::string s;
std::getline(file, s);
```

Then, if you need it as a character array, you can use `std::string.c_str()` to convert into C style string.

Answer (score 0):

Just with a quick look at yuour code, it looks like you are using a 20 character array to store

```
TTFTFTTTFTFTFFTTFTTF
```

which is exactly 20 characters

getline function will read a string which should always end with a `null` or `\n` character, so to read your string of 20 characters yours array size should actually 21. Try changing to

```
const int NUM_QUESTIONS = 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the beginning on how to read a file. In practice you would need to add a lot more error handling though (never trust your programs input).

Naming of functions and variables is very important to so you can read the final code like a book (or at least a recipe)

Building blocks : [std::string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), [range based for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Also not loading is done from a generic stream class not a filestream. This will make your code more reusable (it can load from any stream now, also those in memory).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream> 
//#include <cstring> not needed
#include <string>
#include <vector>

//const int NUM_QUESTIONS = 20;
//not needed with vector you can adapt to the input size at runtime

// using namespace std; NO Unlearn this.

// then model your input
struct answer_t
{
    std::string student_id;
    std::string input;
};

struct exam_data_t
{
    std::string correct_answers;
    std::vector<answer_t> student_answers;
};


// make functions
exam_data_t load_exam_data(std::istream& stream)
{
    exam_data_t answers;
    std::getline(stream, answers.correct_answers);

    // toda add more input validation, answer text lengths 
    // should be equal to length of correct_answers etc...

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(stream, line))
    {
        answer_t answer;

        // simple split line based on assumption that
        // input is correct (usually not true in practice!)

        answer.student_id = line.substr(0ul, 8ul);
        answer.input = line.substr(10ul);
        answers.student_answers.push_back(answer);
    }

    return answers;
}


int main() 
{
    // simulate input file
    std::istringstream input_file
    {
        "TTFTFTTTFTFTFFTTFTTF\n"
        "ABC54102 T FTFTFTTTFTTFTTF TF\n"
        "DEF56278 TTFTFTTTFTFTFFTTFTTF\n"
        "ABC42366 TTFTFTTTFTFTFFTTF\n"
        "ABC42586 TTTTFTTT TFTFFFTF\n"
    };

    //std::ifstream input_file{ "Ch8_Ex6Data.txt" };
    auto exam_data = load_exam_data(input_file);

    std::cout << "correct answers : " << exam_data.correct_answers << "\n";

    for (const auto& answer : exam_data.student_answers)
    {
        std::cout << "Student : " << answer.student_id << ", answer = " << answer.input << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::istream::getline` ensures the extracted data is terminated by a 0 char. This makes extracting 20 chars from the stream given a buffer of size 20 to write to impossible. (You may realize that the `F` at the end of the line is missing.)

You've got several options here:

1. Increase the buffer size by 1
2. Use [`read`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) instead of `getline`. I only recommend doing this, if the exact number of chars to extract is known or you've validating that the input read contains only `'T'` and `'F'` anyways.
3. Use `getline`, ignore the fail bit being set, and then extract another char using `get`. (Not recommended, since this makes for code that isn't as easy to read as the other options.)

The following code demonstrates all of those options:

```
constexpr size_t NumQuestions = 20;

template<class F>
void RunExample(char const* functionName, F&& readLine)
{
    std::istringstream in("TTFTFTTTFTFTFFTTFTTF\nFFTFTFFFTFTFTTFFTFFT");
    std::cout << "Running " << functionName << '\n';
    readLine(in, std::cout);
    readLine(in, std::cout);
}

int main() {
    RunExample("getline(increased buffer size)", [](std::istream& in, std::ostream& out) // 1.
        {
            char buffer[NumQuestions + 1];

            in.getline(buffer, NumQuestions + 1, '\n');
            assert(in.gcount() >= NumQuestions);

            out << std::string_view(buffer, NumQuestions) << '\n';
        });
    RunExample("read+ignore", [](std::istream& in, std::ostream& out) // 2.
        {
            char buffer[NumQuestions];
            in.read(buffer, NumQuestions);
            in.ignore(1, '\n');

            out << std::string_view(buffer, NumQuestions) << '\n';
        });
    RunExample("getline+get+ignore", [](std::istream& in, std::ostream& out) // 3.
        {
            char buffer[NumQuestions];

            in.getline(buffer, NumQuestions, '\n');
            assert(in.gcount() == (NumQuestions - 1));
            assert(!in.bad());
            in.clear(); // remove fail bit set since the delimiter is not encountered before exhausting the buffer storage
            auto const lastChar = in.get();
            assert(lastChar != '\n');
            assert(lastChar != std::istream::traits_type::eof());
            buffer[NumQuestions - 1] = lastChar;
            in.ignore(1, '\n'); // skip newline after the input just extracted, if present

            out << std::string_view(buffer, NumQuestions) << '\n';
        });
}
```